# Programmatically change logo

Tags: 7, media

I tried two versions:
1.

```
$form_state = array();
form_load_include($form_state, 'inc', 'system', 'system.admin');
$form_state['values']['var'] = 'theme_settings';
$form_state['values']['logo_upload'] = file_save_upload('/path/to/logo.jpg');

drupal_form_submit('system_theme_settings_submit', $form_state);
```

2.

```
 variable_set('logo_path', '/path/to/my/uploaded/logo.jpg');
```

but none of them worked.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That setting is part of the theme settings variable; each setting is put in an array and that array is serialised as the value of the main theme settings variable.

You can set this value programmatically like so:

```
$theme_name = 'garland';  
$var_name = 'theme_' . $theme_name . '_settings';

$settings = variable_get($var_name, array());

$settings['logo_path'] = $new_path;

variable_set($var_name, $settings);
```

Comment: Clive can you comment a bit more about this? Your code  is exactly what I'm looking for, but does it go in a module or theme-settings.php type file? Which hook would this go in?

Comment: Couldn't say - whatever context you need to run the code in is where to put it. Might be in response to a form submission, node being updated, or any of the other dozens of events that Drupal raises. The code is context free so just run it wherever your use case tells you to

Comment: @Clive Possible to do this via `drush vset`? Or do you have to use `drush ev`?

Comment: @blue928 A custom modules install-hook in an .install file would be a good place I think. There you could also reset your custom settings within an uninstall-hook later.